# Use VBA to capture the fields in pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

We can use below code to build a Pivot Table (This is a pivot table created by Power Pivot).

```
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CubeFields(FieldName)
            .Orientation = Orientation
            .Position = Position
```

Is there some way to reverse the process? Suppose user has built a pivot table. We use VBA to capture the fields used on the table (find out corresponding `FieldName(s), Orientation(s), and Position(s)`) and save them, so next time, user can just run the macro and create the same pivot table again.

Thanks

Comment: For Each objCubeFld in ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields.....Next objCubeFld  Use this syntax.  Then work on the code to figure out how to save the values somewhere and then how to reload the pivotTable.  If you have a specific problem with that, ask a question about it.

Comment: @OpiesDad Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried it, and it worked, but there are some questions. It cannot differentiate whether the fields are in Row, or in Column, or in Filter.

Comment: The objCubeFld.Orientation property doesn't work?

Comment: This shows what the values represent: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835617.aspx The CubeField.Orientation property should return a XLPivotFieldOrientation  value

Comment: Also, this won' t show the fields that are data fields.  For this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577023/excel-pivotfield-orientation-is-wrong

Comment: @OpiesDad Thanks. Based on the website you gave to me, I tested out that I can loop through `For Each objCubeFld In pvt.PageFields` to find the filters, `pvt.DataFields` to find the values, `pvt.RowFields` to find the rows and `pvt.ColumnFields` to find the columns. So loop through the pivot table 4 times to find all the fields. Do you know any other more efficient ways?

Comment: You only need to loop through twice.  The .PivotFields will show all in the Column, Row, or Filter.  The .DataFields will show all in the Data section.

Comment: @OpiesDad If I use `.PivotFields`, it will show all in Column, Row, or Filter, but cannot tell which fields in which. I if use `PageFields`, `RowFields`, and `ColumnFields`, I can tell which fields are in Row, which fields are in Column, and which fields are in Filter. Please tell me if I am not correct.

Comment: Use objCubeFld.Orientation and the msdn link above to determine which field is in which section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112541/discussion-between-newguycomesin-and-opiesdad).

Comment: objCubeFld.Orientation = 2 for a column field, 3 for a page field and 1 for a row field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @OpiesDad. Below will work.

```
Sub Func1()
Dim objCubeFld As PivotField
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
For Each objCubeFld In pvt.PivotFields
MsgBox objCubeFld & "-" & objCubeFld.Orientation
Next objCubeFld
End Sub
```